# Cannot set default gateway to specific LAN

Tags: networking, gateway

Recently, I am trying to add a default gateway to my ubuntu machine to be able to send/receive packets from an another LAN through the router. However, everything I do the result is the following:

```
    vag@ubuntu:~$ route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    192.168.141.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
    x.y.z.w         0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
    0.0.0.0         192.168.141.2   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

What I am trying to do (at least I think) is to create a line with the given information

```
    192.168.20.0    192.168.1.254   255.255.255.0  xx     xxx xxxx        xxxx
```

I don't want to have connection on the internet and this is what I think **0.0.0.0 Destination** and **gateway** represent in the above table. I want just to connect to the LAN.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The command you have to run is:

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.254
```